# How to fetch custom field values in a custom object in Salesforce using Visual Force and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I have created a custom object MyObj_*c. Then I created a field MyField*_c. Now I created a separate tab for this where I can input values for that field. I entered some values to store in a record.

Now I need to access the value of that field from a VisualForce page using JavsScript. How can I do that ???

When I tried `<apex:outputField value="{!MyObj__c.MyField__c}" id="abcd"/>`

I get the default value of that field, not the value stored in that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you leveraging a standardController on your VF page? If you are using a custom controller, you will need to reference your record by variable name rather than the object API name.

Comment: Thanks, I made a custom controller and it works. But I used the Object API name and it is working fine.